# Redirect all unknown domains

Tags: apache, debian, subdomain

I want to redirect all unknown subdomains in apache, can you help me ? Exemple : " aaa.mydomain.com / bbb.mydomain.com / ccc.mydomain.com " redirect to " all.domain.com ".

My current host :

>

```
    ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
    ServerName domain.dev
    ServerAlias administration.domain.dev
    ServerAlias agence.domain.dev
    ServerAlias css.domain.dev
    ServerAlias dev.domain.dev
    ServerAlias dome.domain.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony/domain/web
    <Directory  /var/www/symfony/domain/web>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    RewriteEngine On
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
            </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_dev.domain.dev.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_dev.domain.dev.log combined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a reverse proxy, look at apache [proxypass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/proxy.html)